# Automate VSCode project setup

Tags: visual-studio-code

Everytime I start a new project, I create a virtual environment, I upgrade pip, initialise a git repo, create .gitignore, requirements.txt, etc.

I'd like to automate this, so that I just start the process, and at the end, the terminal has the virtual environment activated.

While I'm mainly using Python, the question applies to any language.

I could chain tasks with the "dependsOn", but that's not the cleanest option.

Does anybody have suggestions? I couldn't find anything useful only.

Comment: If you really find yourself doing that a couple of times that's worth automating, I think a simple `.bat` file with a couple of commands you ran manually otherwise will do it.

Comment: I was hoping for something more "integrated".
That said, I gave it a try, and it's not bad. I'll add an answer with that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggest by [Alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2557263/alejandro), I wrote a script (Powershell) and put it in the folder containing all my projects

```
Write-Host "=====> Python project setup <====="
Write-Host "Creating virtual environment"
if ( Test-Path -Path ./venv )
{
    Write-Host "Virtual environment already exists"
}
else
{
    python -m venv venv
}
./venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1 > $null

Write-Host "Installing packages"
python -m pip install --upgrade pip > $null
pip install wheel black > $null

Write-Host "Initialise git repo"
if ( Test-Path -Path ./.git )
{
    Write-Host "Repository already exists"
}
else
{
    git init
}

Write-Host "Creating files"
New-Item -Path . -Name "requirements.txt" -ItemType "file" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue >$null
New-Item -Path . -Name ".gitignore" -ItemType "file" -Value "venv/`n" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue >$null
```

And then, in the User tasks, I added this

```
{
    "label": "Setup Python project",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "../setup.ps1",
    "args": ["${input:folder}"],
    "presentation": {
        "echo": false,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": true,
        "panel": "shared",
    },
    "problemMatcher": []
}
```